# how to stop from an infinite while loop javascript with if-else conditional check

Tags: javascript

please I don't know why this program won't run successfully. I truly want to break out from the while loop, and I have checked the conditions to enable me break out but when those conditions are met, the loop still continues and run infinitely.

I have tried do-while loop and now also while loop and yet I can't get it working.

Please I need someone to help me.

```
var smallestValue = function(n) {
    let q = 0,
    smallestvalue = 2,
    factors = [],
    stopme = true,
    stopme1 = true;
    while (stopme1) {
        console.log(stopme1 + '===')
        console.log(stopme + '====00')
        if (stopme && stopme1) {
            console.log(stopme1 + ' seee ooo ' + stopme)
            q = Math.floor(n / smallestvalue);

            console.log(n + ' = ' + smallestvalue + ' = ' + q)
            console.log(factors)
            if ((q === 1 && n === smallestvalue) && factors.length === 0) {
                console.log('aaaaaa')
                stopme = false;
                n = smallestvalue;
                factors = [];
                q = 1;
            }
            else {
                if (n % smallestvalue === 0 && q > 1) {
                    factors.push(smallestvalue);
                    n = q;
                    console.log(n + 'xxxx');
                    console.log(factors + 'xxx')
                    if (n % smallestvalue !== 0) {
                        smallestvalue++;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log(smallestvalue + ' === ' + factors.length)
                    if (factors.length === 0) {
                        smallestvalue++;
                        q = Math.floor(n / smallestvalue);
                        console.log(smallestvalue + ' bbhhh')
                        console.log(n + ' ' + smallestvalue + ' ' + q + ' ' + factors.length)
                        if (q === 1 && n === smallestvalue && factors.length === 0) {
                            console.log("please stop me here");
                            stopme = false;
                            n = smallestvalue;
                            factors = [];
                            q = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(factors)
                        factors.push(n);
                        console.log(factors)
                        let sum = 0;
                        for (let i = 0; i < factors.length; i++) {
                            sum += factors[i];
                        }
                        console.log(sum)
                        n = sum;
                        smallestvalue = 2;
                        factors = [];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            stopme = false;
            stopme = false;
            stopme1 = false;
            stopme1 = false;
            stopme = false;
            n = smallestvalue;
            factors = [];
            q = 1;
        }
        stopme1 = stopme;
        console.log(stopme1)
        console.log(stopme)
        if (stopme === false && stopme1 === false) {
            console.log('i still want to stop here but no way');
            return;
            //break;
        }
    }
    return n;
};
```

Comment: I just ran your function with `n` being `200`, and it is finite: not stuck in a loop.

Comment: please try n=15

Comment: It still is finite for me. What I think you're saying is that it doesn't stop exactly when you want it to?

Comment: I would highly encourage to put ```debugger``` and then see when it goes to infinite loop.

Comment: yes, you are right. when it ought to stop, it picks a new n value and run infinitely, especially when n = 15, i want it to stop when n is reduced to n = 5, and smallestvalue which is the divisor is increased from 2 to 5, in which n = smallestvalue = 5 and quotient = 1 and factors.length = 0. at this point i want to break from the while loop and return n=5, but the function picks arbitrary value to run infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line

```
break;
```

directly after the line that says `console.log("please stop me here");`.

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that you always want your function to return a number, and never `undefined`. It's not clear to me what your function is supposed to do, but if my previous sentence is true, you will probably also want to add the line `break;` directly after the line that says `console.log('i still want to stop here but no way');`.